# How can I automatically load and attach imported functions on project open in package dev?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

When I'm opening a R *package* project on my computer, I'd like to automatically load and attach `library()` all the packages which are listed in the respective `NAMESPACE` of the given package as `import()`s (not `importFrom()`s).

This is helpful, because it allows me to more quickly interactively evaluate code. Otherwise, I waste time with dealing, with, say,

```
glue("foo")
# Error in glue("foo") : could not find function "glue"
```

even though I *have* glue in my `NAMESPACE`.

Not a huge thing, bit shaves off some seconds and quite a bit of frustration.

Please notice that this only applies in the context of *package* development.
In non-package projects, I can just place `library()` into my `.Rprofile`, but this would be redundant in the case of packages, where said packages *are* already declared in `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Since you've mentioned `devtools` (in your answer), are you using `devtools::load_all()` for interactive development of your package?

Comment: yes I am, but `devtools::load_all()` alone doesn't seem to load packages declared as imports in `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Huh, sorry, I thought it did ...

Comment: is it because `devtools::load_all` reads `DESCRIPTION` and not `NAMESPACE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to add the following to the `.Rprofile` at my project (and package) root:

```
if (Sys.getenv()["LOGNAME"] %in% c("foo_user", "bar_user")) {
  message("I seem to be running on a dev machine, so I am doing some preparatory steps.")
  imports <- devtools::parse_ns_file()$imports  # capture all imports from namespace file
  imports <- purrr::discard(.x = imports, .p = is.list)  # only take the import(), not the importFrom() declarations.
  purrr::walk(.x = imports, .f = library, character.only = TRUE)
}
```

Does this seem like an ok way to go about it?

---

**Update** (already included in the above)

It seems that some CI systems (Appveyor) don't like `devtools::...`) and other calls in `.Rprofile`, perhaps because they don't have this and other packages available at whatever stage in the build cycle `.Rprofile` is called (pretty early?).
So it might seem wise to wrap the whole shebang in an if clause to call it only on the local dev machines.

On macOS, `Sys.getenv()["LOGNAME"]` gives the short user name, so I'm using that to identify my dev machine.

Let me know if anyone has better ideas.

Comment: I would agree that a project-specific `.Rprofile` is the right way to go here.